# Check whether specific time has surpassed using Firebase timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am stuck on a problem in Firebase where I have would like to:

1. Check the  date and time using the `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.
2. Increment the value of a variable when the date changes.

I have understood how to capture the time and date but how can I know whether the time is 2:00PM of 6 Feb has surpassed and change the value value of the variable after that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date into milliseconds for both for comparison then simply perform a magnitude check.

Comment: but the change has to be reflected each time the date changes. that is the change is to be shown every day at that same time in the variable @Caspain

Comment: I am unable to understand how. If you could give me an example. That would be really helpful